# multilevel ul list positioning

Tags: css, list, positioning, unordered

I have a ul list menu that goes three levels deep. I'd like all the FirstMenu list items to sit next to each other horizontally, while the nested and vertically aligned Second and ThirdMenus sit *below* the three horizontal FirstMenu items. Nothing I've tried so far in the CSS (floats, relative/absolute positioning, margins/padding) prevents the FirstMenus from dropping down to sit below the Second and ThirdMenus. Suggestions welcomed!

```
    <ul id="footermenu">
     <li class="firstfootermenu">FirstMenu1      
      <ul class="subfootermenu">
        <li>SecondMenu1
          <ul class="subsubfootermenu">
            <li>ThirdMenu1</li>
            <li>ThirdMenu2</li>
            <li>ThirdMenu3</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    <li class="secondfootermenu"><a href="#">FirstMenu2</a></li>
    <li class="secondfootermenu"><a href="#">FirstMenu3</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top` or `float: left` on the immediate successors of the first `ul`: http://jsfiddle.net/jmAUJ/ or http://jsfiddle.net/8etkS/

EDIT: Updated jsFiddle with new layout http://jsfiddle.net/jmAUJ/1/

Comment: Sorry - one followup question. The width of the Second/ThirdMenus determines the positioning of the FirstMenus, so for example if I have very long ThirdMenus, it pushes the last two FirstMenus all the way to the right. Thoughts?

Comment: Here's a PNG of the design I'm trying to replicate: http://i48.tinypic.com/5dm5uw.png

Comment: I edited the original answer. The trick is to use `overflow: visible` and `white-space: nowrap`.